# Why are single-electron states occupied at $T=0$ in superconductors?

Tags: solid-state-physics, temperature, superconductivity, bosons, density-of-states

Some textbooks show a density of states where the single-electron states below the Fermi energy are occupied at $T=0$ (see picture). However, I thought that at $T=0$ all electrons are paired. Hence this would mean that they are bosons and should not show up in the density of states for single electrons. How is that possible?

[image: Density of states at T=0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In few words, I believe that this picture is misleading, since there is a totally equivalent picture which makes your point more intuitive. However, I need to go through the details.

**Mathematical analysis**

You can see this very clearly from the BCS theory. The BCS Hamiltonian reads
$$
H = \sum_k \Psi_k^{\dagger} \left( 
\begin{array}{cc}
\varepsilon_k & \Delta \\
\Delta & -\varepsilon_k
\end{array}
\right) \Psi_k,
$$
where I have introduced the Nambu spinor containing usual electron operators
$$
\Psi_k = \left( \begin{array}{c} c_{k\uparrow} \\ c^{\dagger}_{-k\downarrow} \end{array} \right).
$$
The BCS Hamiltonian does not commute with the particle number operator, meaning that the number of fermions in the system is not a good quantum number, and is not fixed.
Now performing a suitable unitary transformation, you can diagonalize the matrix and get a diagonal Hamiltonian in terms of new fermionic operators $\alpha_{k\sigma}$, $\sigma=\uparrow, \downarrow$:
$$
H = \sum_{k\sigma} \lambda_k \alpha^{\dagger}_{k\sigma} \alpha_{k\sigma} - \sum_k \lambda_k
$$
where $\lambda_k = \sqrt{\varepsilon_k^2 + \Delta^2}$.
Notice that $\lambda_k >0$ for every $k$, as long as the system is gapped ($\Delta\neq 0$).
So what is the ground state of such system, provided that you don't have any constraint on the particle number?
Well, it's the state with no $\alpha$-fermions at all, since the presence of any $\alpha$-fermion would increase the energy by an amount $\lambda_k$!
Moreover, the ground state energy is $E_0 = - \sum_k \lambda_k$.
This makes totally sense: all the electrons are in the condensate, $\alpha$-fermions represent quasi-particle excitations on top of it, and in the ground state there are no such excitations.

Now the misleading - but equivalent - picture.
There is a trivial trick to make things more symmetric: let's write the identity $\lambda_k \alpha^{\dagger}_{k\sigma} \alpha_{k\sigma} = (\lambda_k/2) (\alpha^{\dagger}_{k\sigma} \alpha_{k\sigma} + 1 - \alpha_{k\sigma} \alpha^{\dagger}_{k\sigma})$, so that the Hamiltonian becomes
$$
H = \sum_k \left( \frac{\lambda_k}{2} \alpha^{\dagger}_{k\sigma} \alpha_{k\sigma} - \frac{\lambda_k}{2} \alpha_{k\sigma} \alpha^{\dagger}_{k\sigma} \right),
$$
Finally let's rewrite the second term introducing the operator $\beta^{\dagger}_{k\sigma} = \alpha_{k\sigma}$ (notice that a $\beta$-fermion can be interpreted as a hole of $\alpha$-fermions):
$$
H = \sum_k \left( \frac{\lambda_k}{2} \alpha^{\dagger}_{k\sigma} \alpha_{k\sigma} - \frac{\lambda_k}{2} \beta^{\dagger}_{k\sigma} \beta_{k\sigma} \right).
$$
The plot you are showing clearly comes out from this Hamiltonian (notice the symmetryc energy bands $\pm \lambda_k/2$). What is the ground state now? Again the state with no $\alpha$-particles, corresponding to the state with the maximum amount of $\beta$-particles! The ground state energy is $E_0 = -\sum_k \lambda_k$, which is again consistent.

The latter approach is more nice and symmetric, but also misleading, because it suggests the wrong idea that the ground state is made by **electrons** filling up the lowest energy band. The correct interpretation is that the system is filled up with **$\beta$-fermions**, or equivalently it is completely empty of $\alpha$-fermions: in either case, if you write down the state in terms of the original electron operators $c_{k\sigma}$, you will get the BCS ground state, i.e. a coherent state of condensed electronic pairs :)